# Error in MCP: At Least 5 relocations are required to fit home range

Tags: r, geospatial

I am very new to R and I am trying to calculate home range of an animal using the MCP method however, getting an error of "At Least 5 relocations are required to fit an home range" even though I have around 2000 points.

Below is the code that I am using

```
animal <- read.csv("E:\\<username>\\Data_Clean.csv")

animal.sp <- animal[, c("idPosition", "longitude", "latitude")]

library(sp)
coordinates(animal.sp) <- c("longitude", "latitude")

proj4string(animal.sp) <- CRS( "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

library(adehabitatHR)

animal.mcp <- mcp(animal.sp, percent = 100)
```

I feel this could be because in the Environment window the lat and lon are being read upto one decimal place as shown in screenshot however, in the dataset values are upto 5 decimal places.

Please let me know if this is the reason and if so what can be done about or I am missing something.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide some data to reproduce the problem, perhaps by using the output of `dput()`.

Comment: @Phil here is the link to google drive where I have uploaded a subset of the data https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o-bqr7BQCky7_Oh4J690JE6jtZyKNWtd?usp=share_link